# What is the difference between NAT / Bridged / Host-Only networking?

Tags: networking, vmware, network-adapter

VMWare: What is NAT vs. Bridged vs. Host-Only?

Comment: An aspect I looked for in this question/answers was any differences in the [OSI network Layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers)

Comment: You can also check the "Overview of Networking Modes" table here https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

Comment: One thing to remember is Bridged mode will mean any network calls bypass your VPN and reveal your IP address and activity on the Internet with no privacy.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Host-only only permits network operations with the Host OS.

NAT mode will mask all network activity as if it came from your Host OS, although the VM can access external resources.

Bridged mode replicates another node on the physical network and your VM will receive it's own IP address if DHCP is enabled in the network.

Comment: will the VM receive it's own IP address in NAT or Host-only mode?

Comment: It will receive an address, but not from the DHCP server. Likely in a completely different range, and not routable on the current LAN. You will see a virtual adapter on the host OS which will have an address in the same range.

Comment: So if the IP is not from a DHCP server is it static?

Comment: I see two vmnet adapters on my host machine (vmnet1 and vmnet8). Which one is my VM?

Comment: Yeap, you got it.

Comment: In bridged mode, vmnet adapter in host machine WILL NOT be used at all ??

Comment: The description of host-only networking in this answer isn't quite accurate and implies that the VM is accessible only by the host OS. See my answer for a more thorough explanation

Comment: as far as I know, you can configure a DHCP server in your host to give a dynamic IP for your VMs

Answer (score 81):

Same concept as the normal network setup :)

- **Host-Only**: The VM will be assigned one IP, but it's only accessible by the box VM is running on. No other computers can access it.
- **NAT**: Just like your home network with a wireless router, the VM will be assigned in a separate subnet, like `192.168.6.1` is your host computer, and VM is `192.168.6.3`, then your VM can access outside network like your host, but no outside access to your VM directly, it's protected.
- **Bridged**: Your VM will be in the same network as your host, if your host IP is `172.16.120.45` then your VM will be like `172.16.120.50`. It can be accessed by all computers in your host network.

Comment: The description of host-only networking in this answer isn't quite accurate and implies that the VM is accessible only by the host OS. See my answer for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: NAT and Bridged seems to be the same. I do not understand the difference. So the HOST is AAA.BBB.CCC.x, and the VM is AAA.BBB.CCC.y in both cases. Where is the difference?

Answer (score 48):

The below table shows the connectivity between VM and Host for different network types.  Please see [Virtualbox Docs: Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for a brief explanation of the modes.

[image: Overview of Networking Modes]

- '**+**' means 'yes, this direction of connection-initiation is possible'
- '**-**' means 'initiating connections in the direction given in the column title is not possible'

'**port forward**' means that you'll have to manually add to the host's network configuration instructing it as follows: "whatever connection requests come to this port on your network adapter are actually meant for this port on this VM, so simply forward it there and not to any host-based listener". This makes the hidden NAT IP and port of the VM (on which a VM service is listening) effectively visible on the host adapter and available to receive requests from external entities. See: [VBox Docs: Configuring Port Forwarding with NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) for an explanation of how this can be easily done.

See also: [Oracle VM VirtualBox: Networking options and how-to manage them](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/post/oracle-vm-virtualbox-networking-options-and-how-to-manage-them), [Virtualbox Networks: In Pictures](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=96608), [VirtualBox Network Settings: Complete Guide](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/)

Comment: That's what means, a picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: Can I ask you a little improvement? Can you add a column that explain if VM can access other ip of the host ip network?

Comment: The "Internal" row is what you're looking for.  From the site mentioned above: "Internal Networking is similar to bridged networking in that the VM can directly communicate with the outside world. However, the "outside world" is limited to other VMs on the same host which connect to the same internal network."

Comment: Anyone, in NAT/NAT Network - why can't the guest connect to host? The gateway/router would have to handle it just like accessing any address on the Internet.

Comment: it looks like "NAT Network" permits both VM <--> HOST ping. Don't understand why the docs says it does not.

Comment: What are "+" and "-"? Do they mean Yes and No?

Comment: NAT is bidirectional (meaning host to guest or guest to host).  But the IP addresses used to access the opposite machine are not consistent.

Answer (score 26):

While the other answers here provide good descriptions for the NAT and Bridged modes, their explanations for Host-only mode are not quite accurate.

From VMware's documentation, under [Configuring Network Connections > Understanding Common Networking Configurations](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html):

> Host-only networking creates **a network that is completely contained within the host computer**. Host-only networking provides a network connection between the virtual machine and the host system by using a virtual network adapter that is visible on the host operating system.

(Emphasis mine.)

Note that it does *not* say that the VM will be accessible only by the host.  The *network* is self-contained, not the *connection*.  This is a subtle but important difference.

Additionally, as pointed out by user5389726598465, under [Creating Virtual Machines > Preparing to Create a New Virtual Machine > 
Selecting the Network Connection Type for a Virtual Machine](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-3B504F2F-7A0B-415F-AE01-62363A95D052.html):

> **With host-only networking, the virtual machine can communicate only with the host system and other virtual machines in the host-only network.** Select host-only networking to set up an isolated virtual network.

You should be aware that the Host-only, NAT, and Bridged modes are aliases to specific virtual networking switches ("VMnets") that are preconfigured for the different behaviors.  As with a normal network switch, all machines connected to the same switch are visible to each other.

**This means that all VMs connected to a host-only network will be visible to the host *and to each other***.  If you want a VM that is visible *only* to the host, you will need to assign it a dedicated VMnet and avoid assigning any other VMs to that VMnet.

Comment: +1 Your answer is correct but the line after your quote in the KB is a better quote: "With host-only networking, the virtual machine can communicate only with the host system and other virtual machines in the host-only network. Select host-only networking to set up an isolated virtual network."

Comment: @user5389726598465 I agree that's a better quote, but I don't see that in the VMware Workstation product documentation. (The link I had was broken, but it's fixed now.) If your quote is from a KB article, can you please provide a reference to it?

Comment: Here's the link: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-3B504F2F-7A0B-415F-AE01-62363A95D052.html. Unfortunately, the other answers seem reasonable so everyone upvotes them and skip your answer not realizing the VM's can still see e/o.

Comment: You quote a thing that says "With host-only networking, the virtual machine can communicate only with the host system and other virtual machines in the host-only network. Select host-only networking to set up an isolated virtual network." <-- Does that mean you can't access the web eg Google.com from the virtual machine? And if you can then what do you actually mean by that quote?

Comment: @barlop Correct, you would not be able to connect to the Internet from a host-only network (unless one of the VMs on that network explictly bridged it).

Answer (score 3):

I installed IIS on virtual machine **C1,H1,B1,N1** and Windows 10 on **C2,H2,B2,N2**.  These 6 VM are on my host computer. I have another laptop connected by ethernet cable connected to same router as my host computer. I arranged them in pair of each switch type. I have tried this combination with port forwarding on my home router and on virtual machine **N1** using NAT switch. This is what I concluded after trying to access the website on each of the device in network. I also configured my Virtual Network Editor settings to create two subnets 3.3.3.0 for VMnet1 (Host only switch) and 2.2.2.0 for VMnet8 (NAT switch). The settings are as below

[image]

Since NAT switch has Virtual Router (2.2.2.2) that also act as (Router + Default gateway + DNS server) for 2.2.2.0 subnet so N1,N2 can access Internet on it. But Host Only switch has no virtual router and default gateway so cannot access internet on H1,H2.

Just to summarize which all device can communicate with each other I have created one diagram for understanding
[image]