# Can a OS on VMWare/Virtual box have a unique LAN IP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox, vmware

To elaborate, can I have for example OSX running virtually on my Windows machine. Where OSX is running an apache web server exposed to localhost. And the windows machine can access it, by going to the Lan IP address of the virtual OSX in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer yes.

As long as the ports are open, you'll be able to access the web server. I would recommend using a linux, as plenty of OSX have issues when running in VM, and depending on your chip (AMD) it can be a nightmare.

Here is a guide on ubuntu, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04
that I've used numerous times, they have plenty of guides on wordpress too if that's where you're going.

Comment: Is there a special setting so that the virtual OS can request an IP via DHCP instead of using the host OS's connection?

Comment: @johndunsworth Yes, depending on the version of VM you're using, you can. I would recommend VMbox, and have the device have a static IP instead of a DHCP. The VM will always use the Host's connection, but the IP will be different.

Comment: Great thanks, I plan on using it to deploy iOS apps in Visual Studio in windows via the 'Connect to a Mac' build option. It asks you for the IP of you mac. OSX then install the app on an iOS device and reports back to the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Typically the VM will either be using **NAT** networking (which means that it is has an IP address local to the host) or will be using **bridged** networking (which makes the VM act like a separate physical machine on your network).

Also see: [What is the difference between NAT / Bridged / Host-Only networking?](https://superuser.com/questions/227505/what-is-the-difference-between-nat-bridged-host-only-networking)