# Isolated Network between 2 VM's - VMWare Workstation

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, malware

I am attempting to create a testing network for school, I am trying to create a network with VMWare that only allows those 2 VM's that would be on that network to communicate.

I am getting into malware analysis and want to make sure my system is going to be completely isolated from those 2 vm's.

I thought the Host-Only option would do what I am looking for, but I guess my host PC is still able to communicate with those VM's

Any help/suggestions would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it will not work with Host Only. Host Only isolates Virtual Machines. I have VMware Workstation V15 here.  You could try setting up NAT and have only the IP addresses of the two machines active. Make sure you have good Anti Virus on the Host.

Followup:  You could put the malware on a USB key and then point the Host Only VM to that USB key and do not allow the USB key on the host.

Comment: Host-only networking does not isolate VMs from each other.  See [my explanation for host-only networking](https://superuser.com/a/1180970/210417).